# Storing strings in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have read a lot of questions on this, and using them I have altered my code and have created code which I thought would work.

I think it's my understanding of C, which is failing me here as I can't see where I'm going wrong.

I get no compilation errors, but when I run i receive 'FileReader.exe has stopped working' from the command prompt.

My code is :

```
void storeFile(){
int i = 0;
char allWords [45440][25];
    FILE *fp = fopen("fileToOpen.txt", "r");
    while (i <= 45440){
        char buffer[25];
        fgets(buffer, 25, fp);
        printf("The word read into buffer is : %s",buffer);
        strcpy(allWords[i], buffer);
        printf("The word in allWords[%d] is : %s", i, allWords[i]);
        //allWords[i][strlen(allWords[i])-1] = '\0';
        i = i + 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

}

There are 45440 lines in the file, and no words longer than 25 char's in length. I'm trying to read each word into a char array named buffer, then store that buffer in an array of char arrays named allWords.

I am trying to get this part working, before I refactor to return the array to the main method (which I feel won't be a fun experience).

Comment: `while (i <= 45440){`: you'll have a problem at the last iteration: buffer overflow

Comment: If a word length on a line is 25, the buffer length needed to read it in entirety is 27 (allowing for the `'\n'` and zero terminator).   Otherwise, the line will be read in two parts.    Your loop `i <= 45440` will also write to `allWords[45411]` which is a buffer overrun

Comment: @Peter: it's been a while but I *thought* that `fgets` reads 25 - 1 characters.

Comment: @Bathsheba - some introductory texts have historically taught that.   They are wrong.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets. Suggests that `count - 1` is read.

Comment: @Bathsheba: that is the hard return. But you forget the zero terminator itself.

Comment: This is above my pay grade. I missed the important point that @dasblinkenlight mentions. I'll tin my answer, and get me coat.

Comment: Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it.  In particular, you're missing a `main()` function, and you probably need to include some standard headers. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to allocate more than a megabyte (45440*25) worth of data in automatic storage. On many architectures this results in stack overflow *before* your file-reading code even gets to run.

You can work around this problem by allocating `allWords` statically, like this

```
static char allWords [45440][25];
```

or dynamically, like this:

```
char (*allWords)[25] = malloc(45440 * sizeof(*allWords));
```

Note that using `buffer` in the call to `fgets` is not required, because `allWords[i]` can be used instead, without `strcpy`:

```
fgets(allWords[i], sizeof(*allWords)-1, fp);
```

Also note that an assumption about file size is unnecessary: you can continue calling `fgets` until it returns `NULL`; this indicates that the end of the file has been reached, so you can exit the loop using `break`.

Comment: It still (desperately) needs those other fixes mentioned in the comments!

Comment: Ah that's sorted it. I have also increased the size to 27 as read in the comments to allow for the characters I didn't take into account. Thanks for your help.